# Nodewords: how do I use hook_metatags_default_values_alter?

Tags: 6, meta-tags

I posted this question a week ago on the *nodewords* issue queue, but have had no reply and I'm stumped.

I want to programatically set the default value for a couple of tags, but the [code comments](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!nodewords!nodewords.api.php/function/hook_metatags_default_values_alter/6) for hook_metatags_default_values_alter read like hieroglyphics to me. An example would allow me to understand clearly. If I want to set the og:latitude tag to the value 43.701536, what should the call look like?

Thanks!

Comment: For future reference: it turns out the version of _nodewords_ documented on DrupalContrib.org (3.x) didn't even exist as a download. My version included no such hook — of course I couldn't get a nonexistent hook to work!

So folks, always double-check the module version when using DrupalContrib.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without ever having used that hook, I would suppose that you could do it very similar to the example in the documentation for [hook_metatags_default_value_alter()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!nodewords!nodewords.api.php/function/hook_metatags_default_values_alter/6):

```
function hook_metatags_default_values_alter(&$values, $parameters) {
  if ($parameters['phase'] == 'post_load' && $parameters['type'] == NODEWORDS_TYPE_USER) {
    $values['og:latitude'] = 43.701536;
  }
}
```

For a better understanding it might be worth the effort to dig through the code of [_nodewords_tag_value](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!nodewords!nodewords.module/function/_nodewords_tag_value/6) which seems to have the only invocation of the hook. You can see there, that it is invoked twice with a different `$phase` parameter. I think I would go for `post_load`, assuming that the defaults are not empty.

For the `type` parameter, you can see the available constants in the [nodewords.module doc](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!nodewords!nodewords.module/6) under constants. This value depends on where you want to alter the tag.

If the above code doesn't work, use [dpm](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/6) or something similar to inspect the `$values` that are passed in. That should give you enough information concerning the expected data.

Comment: Indeed.  And the only other comment I would add is that type included (`NODEWORDS_TYPE_USER`) here would restrict this to user profile pages, so, you may need to change or ignore that.  All the types supported are listed at the very beginning of `nodewords.module`.

Comment: Belated reply: thank you! Your comments were very helpful and, beyond this specific issue, gave me some great insight at how one approaches unfamiliar modules.